# Manually setup react for electron without webpack-dev-server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

I am trying to setup react for my electron app.

My main aim is to use react native in electron without using any development server.

Using Development server with electron apps just creates more problems than before.

I will be using a webpack to setup react but no development server should be created.
I tried bable only without webpack but it seems to have less functionality.

Also how must i use electron with the compiled react during development and building the final electron app.

Answer (score 0):

Install the following dependencies:

```
npm i webpack webpack-cli html-webpack-plugin html-loader @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react --save-dev
```

create a .babelrc with :

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

create webpack.config.js with:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "",//Your location to index.html which react renders to
      filename: "./index.html" //Output file name
    })
  ]
};
```

Create a index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>How to set up React, Webpack, and Babel</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Afterwards create a basic react app.

Also create a index.js in the same folder as index.html and add this line in index.js:

```
import Form from ""; //Location to react app
```

Add the following script to package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

Finally execute this line and your compiled code will be in dist folder:

```
npm run build
```

Now, to add to electron you can change paths according to your electron project and point the index.html in Electron's main.js to the one in dist folder.

Also, when using electron use the webpack to execute only the src folder and not outside.
Keep electron js scripts away form the webpack.